# Convert from bigint to time only

Tags: sql, sql-server, qliksense

I have big-int data, and I want to convert it from Big-int to just time, for example I have this value 53006745 for ' 14hrs 43min '
Please help me to write the query in SQL Server, so that will convert big-int into minutes.

Comment: I don't see the relation between `53006745` and `14hrs 43min`

Comment: Guessing the relation is that's the number of milliseconds and he has not quite given the right value - 14hrs 43 mins would be 52980000, 53006745 is 14 hours, 43 minutes, and 26.745 seconds.- so close if we assume the OP rounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You're looking Pure `Time` you could try below `SQL` Query which will give Minutes from Your `Integer` Value:

```
DECLARE @value INT = 53006745

SELECT DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEADD(s, CONVERT(BIGINT, @value) / 1000, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1-1-2017 00:00:00'))) [Minutes];
```

**Result :**

```
Minutes
43
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for yourself in `SQL` :

> SELECT DATEADD(s, CONVERT(BIGINT, 53006745 ) / 1000,
>   CONVERT(DATETIME,
>        '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))

This code return 1970-01-01 14:43:26.000 as you like

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Value INT = 53006745

SELECT 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Value/3600000) + ':'                            -- Hours
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Value%3600000/60000), 2) + ':'      -- Minutes
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Value%3600000%60000/1000), 2) + '.' -- Seconds
    + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Value%1000), 3)                    -- Milliseconds
```